# Struggling to create an index for my PSQL Query

Tags: index, index-tuning, psql

I'm running a query on a dataset that's got 30 million rows in and will only continue to grow, the table is
customer_actions (Table size is 2416 MB)

```
create table customer_actions
(
    id          bigint not null
        constraint customer_actions_pkey
            primary key,
    action      text,
    customer_id bigint,
    product_id  bigint,
    item_type   text,
    create_date timestamp
);
```

I've tried a large variety of indexes, but looking at the exaplin of the query, nothing is being hit

```
SELECT customer_id, product_id, count(*) AS count
from customer_actions
WHERE action = 'a2b'
      AND item_type = 'wine'
      AND create_date BETWEEN current_timestamp - INTERVAL '2 Years' AND current_timestamp
GROUP BY customer_id, product_id

SELECT customer_id, product_id, count(*) AS count
from customer_actions
WHERE action = 'view'
      AND item_type = 'wine'
      AND create_date BETWEEN current_timestamp - INTERVAL '2 Years' AND current_timestamp
GROUP BY customer_id, product_id

SELECT customer_id, product_id, count(*) AS count
from customer_actions
WHERE action = 'buy'
      AND item_type = 'wine'
      AND create_date BETWEEN current_timestamp - INTERVAL '2 Years' AND current_timestamp
GROUP BY customer_id, product_id
```

Indexes I've tried, some of them I know wouldn't have worked but I was grasping at straws, all the ones with a condition on the end have also been tried without the condition. Don't suppose anyone can point me in the right direction, I'm pretty new to PSQL and don't yet have a deep understanding of indexes.

```
CREATE  INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_14 on customer_actions (customer_id, product_id, 
create_date, action, item_type) where action = 'a2b'
CREATE  INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_15 on customer_actions (customer_id, product_id, action, item_type) where action = 'a2b'
CREATE  INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_16 on customer_actions (customer_id, product_id) where action = 'a2b'
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_11 on customer_actions (item_type, action ) where item_type = 'wine' and action = 'a2b';
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_12 on customer_actions (item_type, action ) where item_type = 'wine' and action = 'view' ;
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_13 on customer_actions (item_type, action ) where item_type = 'wine' and action = 'buy' ;
CREATE INDEX idx_time on customer_actions using brin (create_date);
create index idx_actions_a2b on customer_actions (action) where action = 'a2b'
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_customer_actions_action_product_cardinality_order on customer_actions (customer_id, product_id, action);
CREATE INDEX id_time_and_other on customer_actions (action, item_type, create_date DESC)
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_customer_actions_product_and_customer on customer_actions (customer_id, product_id)
CREATE  INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_14 on customer_actions (customer_id, product_id, create_date, action, item_type)
CREATE  INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_14 on customer_actions (customer_id, product_id, create_date, action)
CREATE  INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_17 on customer_actions (customer_id, product_id)
```

The exaplin of the query is

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=745877.49..1182094.60 rows=1527687 width=24)
"  Group Key: customer_id, product_id"
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=745877.49..1143902.43 rows=3055374 width=24)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=744877.46..790236.43 rows=1527687 width=24)
"              Group Key: customer_id, product_id"
              ->  Sort  (cost=744877.46..752397.99 rows=3008210 width=16)
"                    Sort Key: customer_id, product_id"
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on customer_actions  (cost=0.00..318363.94 rows=3008210 width=16)
                          Filter: ((action = 'a2b'::text) AND (item_type = 'wine'::text) AND (create_date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND (create_date >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '2 years'::interval)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best index for a query will group all the wanted records together

Immagine if you said `ORDER BY action,item_type, create_date`

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ca_aid on customer_actions (action, item_type, create_date);
```

Comment: Ahh okay, this index worked thank you. I was searching for a create date that spanned the entire database. Doing an 18 month used the index!